# Typescript - Computed generic type not working well

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm trying to set a Generic type that will accept 2 parameters and return a function.
First parameter - The type of the single parameter of the returned function
Second Parameter - need to get true if dev wants the returned function parameter to be required.

Somehow it's just not working
The Val is inferred to string but it still thinks it's not a string

Any help will be appreciated

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkEMDsBNIC4HsBOBPUBeUCUFcBTUAM1VBQIEc8BLC2UAB0hUgFsCECUBnAKAIAPRqgQ40jIgDVIAGxrwENJNABieaAGMlKgDwAVLKA0BraEgDu0ADSgAkjyhxEqDNlPmrAPix9QumVkjBydFV1AhLjgeHHwiAH5QQwAuJNAAH2M4AmIaaAJYLwAKADc5VMCASiwfXEIM0B5cPIBzAG4%20Ts0VJpwCJoq5BURlNQ1tUd0mlFbbOoIfbFK5aswfAG8-ck48FGhQMtkOgF8Ovi4mooByESRGK8rOkAhINAAjIgQACyJuilAkMQcD9QDQeDx6m88GILAQ6LBZBgaGJIJpNARGAgYjAMAgJERAUwWOxONx7FdZEFmOCcEhQQhOhcEEUAKxsx5MorzDn9ZnQPCUnmXdbHR5AA)

```
// Mandatory = true for required parameters
export type ValidationFunction<T = unknown, IsMandatory = unknown> =
 <Val = IsMandatory extends true ? T : T | undefined>(val: Val) => true | string;


const test: ValidationFunction<string, true> = (val) => { // error!
//    ~~~~
//  Type 'Val' is not assignable to type 'string | true'.
  return val;
};

test('poop')

// Maybe the core of the issue but weirdly it accepts
// any type of parameter I'll pass to it

test(555)
test(true)
test(null)
test({})
```

Comment: Can we get code as text and a playground? I am unable to copy/paste your image and work with your code (because I can't edit an image as text :p).

Comment: Sure, added to post, sorry about that

Comment: I don't understand why your function type is itself generic with type parameter `Val` that defaults to something... if you make it a regular non-generic function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDDP6N) then does it work as expected?

Comment: You are right, I'm not sure what lead me to it, but this makes much more sense. But I would still love to understand why the first implementation didn't work as expected.

Comment: Because you don't want it to be a generic function?  Because type parameter defaults are not constraints?  `<T = X>(t: T) => void` doesn't constrain `T` to `X` at all; it just means `T` will fall back to `X` if the compiler can't infer `T` otherwise.  So it doesn't work because it doesn't express what you're trying to do at all.  Not sure how best to explain it.

Comment: I will write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making `ValidationFunction<T, M>` itself a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with one type parameter `Val` which has a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `IsMandatory extends true ? T : T | undefined`. But it doesn't look like you intend for it to be generic at all, and even if you did, the type parameter `Val` merely *defaults* to something; it isn't [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) at all.  So `test` accepts and returns a completely unconstrained `Val`, which may or may not have anything to do with `string`.

If you change the default to a constraint, things start working how you want:

```
export type ValidationFunction<T = unknown, IsMandatory = unknown> =
  <Val extends IsMandatory extends true ? T : T | undefined>(val: Val) => true | string;
//     ^^^^^^^ <-- constraint, not default

const test: ValidationFunction<string, true> = (val) => {
  return val;
}; // okay

test('') // okay
test(555) // error
test(true) // error
test(null) // error
test({}) // error
```

But again, you don't even really want this to be generic.  We can just replace `Val` with its constraint and things continue to work how you want:

```
export type ValidationFunction<T = unknown, IsMandatory = unknown> =
  (val: IsMandatory extends true ? T : T | undefined) => true | string;


const test: ValidationFunction<string, true> = (val) => {
  return val;
}; // okay

test('') // okay
test(555) // error
test(true) // error
test(null) // error
test({}) // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEATJBvAUEpEAHjAPYBOALkhQJ4zIBqIANgJbogWsnABiArsHhceAHgAqSALxJBAa2AkA7sAA0SAJJQAsiGAcK5GtNnAFy4AD5pefElFNmJrbv2cjBQhQj6o1MvzIAPxIkgBcoUgAPqboEABmrMAQ6JYAFABuLBGOAJTS1hQByDFQRUkA5gDcOLX48Dxl1NAUOSzsnNx8gsJdomVklepFgdYymSz5Uta4dkhkEBT8ZMBIWcw1+AC+NbbeZWkA5IC8G4CVO4e5ey1pAKx3l-j7FGkjEA-NB8D8zMzvT2lYLaXHBbWqgSCwBDIFCLbxkbC2IikSjUOiMdoGLoCIQiYASEzyRQqdQuPQGDwyQkWMa2fAOFieby+TQ6MnuMjGIhM9B+V5IELhSIxQRxRLJVITZhtX4FfyBaJIAaVTZIAD0qrmSAAejrdVr7ABaA1IBrAAYgJIUdSKKiikDfCh1E2NKhPaUdXHY3piJXACrDYpjJCSqYzWnzRbLVbrFU7NUakhyEA0J3-E7nfLqpCJ5NXA53G6ZjUQMhkch556vIsEUvlx7XL4-aslstkCsAoHxmut2qg8HQOCIVAtBH4JHkV1opCOD1Ynq4-GUsxEtQs1zkjkE5fUmxzSURUluQybrk+Hly4KRCKSYX6BJJFKhi8K33VWq2U1NN3TjGdHhehdXwDUYTBDWVZjsBYlhWNYWFjXZ6wOdMLi7HMU0Q54C2bWs2wwl5imwns8MbGUsxbOsPmeQFCPLXsgA)

Comment: So  a string? Cool!

Answer (score 0):

### Invalid answer:

Looks to me like you're saying that your `ValidationFunction` for some reason wants to always return `string | true` - why?

I'd just do it like that

```
export type ValidationFunction<T = unknown, IsMandatory = unknown> =
 <Val = IsMandatory extends true ? T : T | undefined>(val: Val) => T;
```

```
test('poop') // no warnings


test(555) // warning 
test(true) // warning
test(null) // warning
test({}) // warning
test([]) // warning
```

### Valid answer:

```
// Mandatory = true for required parameters
export type ValidationFunction<T = unknown, IsMandatory = unknown> =
  (val: IsMandatory extends true ? T : T | undefined) => true | string;


const test: ValidationFunction<string, true> = (val) => {
  return val;
};

test('poop')

// Maybe the core of the issue but weirdly it accepts any type of parameter I'll pass to it

test(555)
test(true)
test(null)
test({})
```

Answer by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) in the comment of the OP's question.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with the actual function initialisation. @JCALZ already answered with working playground in the question's comments

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood some stuff.